# Regarding binding array to gridview

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I have created session array :

```
 int[] a = (int[])Session["values"];
```

Now i have to bind this value to my gridview. I have one column (boundfield in my gridview) in gridview.
I used code to bind array to gridview as follows, but its giving last value only as i want all the values to bind :

```
     for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                str = "select * from Quest_Info where Quest_id='" + a[i] + "' order by Quest_id";
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(str, sqlconn);
                ds2 = new DataSet();
                da2.Fill(ds2, "Result");
            reviewgrid.DataSource = ds2;
            reviewgrid.DataBind();
}
```

Which code will work for this?
Asp.net, c#
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code may not work because you are trying to bind gridview in the for loop which keep repeating and will result to bind only one last array id in the end.

You may try to prepare query out front before binding the gridview as example below.

```
string questIds = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (questIds.Length > 0)
        questIds += ", ";

    questIds += a[i];  
}

 string strSQL = "select * from Quest_Info where Quest_id IN ("+ questIds + ") order by Quest_id";
 SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(str, sqlconn);
 ds2 = new DataSet();
 da2.Fill(ds2, "Result");
 reviewgrid.DataSource = ds2;
 reviewgrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: In this code when i use response.write then its giving right values of questIds but wrong values in gridview, in response.write it gives 5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4 but actual in gridview it gives 1 2 1 3 4 6 5

Comment: I saw 'order by' clause in your query. so the result will be sorted in ascending order in your gridview.

Comment: no i removed that clause & checked also. 1 is also repeating. but in response.write takes right values i.e questIds why not in gridview

Comment: I can't think of any other reasons. you may check your content of the table, Quest_Info. whether quest_id there is duplicate or not.